# Memory access time in deep cache hierarchy

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I am trying to solve an exercise question from Computer architecture textbook. The book includes the equation for calculating memory access time (MAT) for up to L2 cache (eq. below), however the exercise has upto L4 cache and  off chip memory access for which I don't understand how to use the equation to calculate Avg MAT.

So, Average memory access time = Hit time_L1 + Miss rate_L1 x (Hit time_L2 + Miss rate_L2xMiss penalty_L2)

In exercise question it mentioned a cache hierarchy as -- >[32 KB L1; 128 KB L2; 2 MB L3; 8 MB L4; off-chip memory] for which the memory access time needs to be calculated.

Given, cache/latency/Miss per thousand instructions values: 32 KB/1/100, 128 KB/2/80, 512 KB/4/50, 2 MB/8/40, 8 MB/16/10. And off chip memory access requires 200 cycles on average. Also, 1000 instructions of a program, an average of 20 memory accesses may exhibit low enough locality and can't be serviced bty 2MB cache which has 20 Miss per thousand instruction.

Could anyone help me to solve the problem?